# find the dimension of $P_{100} $?

Tags: linear-algebra

let $P_n$ denote the real vector space of all polynomials in two variables
of degree strictly less than $n$    for $n \ge  1, n \in \mathbb{N}$

find the  dimension of $P_{100} $?

i thinks dimension of $P_{100} =  101$ beacause dimension of $P_{n}= n+1$

Is it correct ?

Comment: No. For instance, in $P_3,$ the polynomials $1,$ $x,$ $y,$ $xy$ $x^2$ and $y^2$ are a basis. Hence, $P_3$ has dimension 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the following in $P_{100}$ which is the real vector space of all polynomials in two variables $x$ and $y$ of degree strictly less than $100$ for :

\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathsf{\text{Degree}} & \mathsf{\text{Number of basis vectors}} & \mathsf{\text{Basis Vectors}}\\\hline
0 \strut & 1 &\text{$1$}\\\hline
1 \strut& 2 &\text{$x,y$}\\\hline
2 \strut & 3 &\text{$x^2,xy,y^2$}\\\hline
\vdots \strut &\vdots &\vdots\\\hline
99\strut & 100 &\text{$x^{99},x^{98}y,\cdots,y^{99}$}\\\hline
\end{array}

So dimension of $P_{100}=\dfrac{100\times101}{2}=4050$.

(Here we have assumed that the variables $x$ and $y$ commute. As an exercise you may try to find $P_{100}$ when $x$ and $y$ do not commute.)

Comment: It would improve your Answer to explain why the final result *totals* the counts in the table.  The table claims to count certain "basis vectors", without mentioning what subspace the dimension is for.  Perhaps just inserting the word *monomial* would help.

Comment: @hardmath: This should suffice.